# Minecraft Regeneration potion help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if I could get a splash potion of regeneration 2, that lasts forever? I have already tried `/give @p potion 1 16385 {Duration:100000}`
it just gives me a regular splash potion of regeneration. I really would like to make it last forever and be regeneration 2 or as high as possible.

Answer (score 4):

`/give @p potion 1 16417` should give you a level II regeneration splash potion; replace `16417` with `16449` for an extended level I.

(After snapshot 15w31a, potions use the `{Potion: type}` tag to indicate their effect; use `regeneration`, `strong_regeneration` or `long_regeneration` in `type` for the respective potions.)

Unfortunately, the lengths and intensities of potions are hard-set; to my memory it is impossible to make custom potions without command-block trickery on, say, a water bottle. However, you could set up a command block, put in a book (or just type each time) the command `/effect @p 10 1000000 2` (which is `/effect [player] [ID] [length] ; see this [wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effects) for all effect IDs).